# single-spa shared component with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, single-spa

Hello, I am building a micro frontend architecture with single-spa.
In my main app (bootstrap), I declare my fragments, my routing and I inject the component library (ex: element UI), and my authentication library (custom).

Everything works fine, display and routing, though:

1. how to use a component of elementUI in a fragment? Example:

```
import {Button} from 'element-ui'
```

I have tried with this code (where component_name is button or other)

```
<component :is="component_name">bla bla</component>
```

but Vue does not recognize this button.

2. How to use utility functions of the authentication library.
   For example recover the access rights for a component?
   Calling the function directly does not work.

Thanks

Comment: are you dealing with dynamic, async components (e.g. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)?

Comment: Yes with <component :is="">. Else, how to use import myComponent from ?

Comment: it was just to be sure: have you tried enclosing your component in a `<keep-alive></keep-alive>` element already (e.g. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive)?

Comment: Why use keep-alive component ? this is only to keep state. The problem is : How reference ElementUI from my boostrap for all fragments? Same for a utility library ?

Comment: AFAIK `<keep-alive/>` is now required for dynamic/async components to work; BTW, I don’t think you did something wrong here; just check your main import of both Bootstrap and Element UI (cfr. https://element.eleme.io/1.4/#/en-US/component/quickstart).

Comment: I’ve tried. Not better. Fragment do not recognize ElementUI. I don’t want install elementui in each fragment. I want it globally

Comment: @BriceChaponneau did you ever find an answer for the questions you had? I am especially interested in the authentication question. If so can you add the answer and mark it as answered?

Comment: Yes. You need to create a styleguide to share components, style…